# How do I use pug with electron-vue?

Tags: vue.js, electron, pug, electron-packager

I built a new electron-Vue application and installed the pug and pug-plain-loader packages. When I run the application, I am getting an error in the console:

```
"Errors compiling template: Component template requires a root element, rather than just text."
```

Is there any **configuration** I need to add or a specific package I need to download in order for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Add package `pug`, `pug-plain-loader`:

```
yarn add pug pug-plain-loader
```

Open file `webpack.renderer.config.js` append more option to `rules`:

```
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        loader: 'pug-plain-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```